# How to create a 'minimalistic' scaffold in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know that creating a scaffold in Rails creates all CRUD actions in the new controller in generates. I was wondering, though, when creating a scaffold, is it possible to tell it to NOT create certain parts of the CRUD, like, for example, generate a scaffold that will only have the Create and the Destroy actions but not the read and delete? Now why would I want to do that? Well, for example, if I'm creating a simple CMS with posts and want to add comments to them, so I want the comments to show on the Posts page but don't want them to have their own separate pages where they show.

Comment: Generate normal scaffold and remove methods/views you don't need :)

Comment: Or use `inherited_resources`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that in Rails at the moment. Rails gives you scaffold on per model bases and not on associations.